# How to seperate a string by " " and store them into 2 different arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to solve a competitive programming practice set. I am only a beginner so please bear with me.

**Here is the problem**

The history teacher at your school needs help in grading a True/False test using his designed
scoring technique. Each correct answer is awarded two points, each wrong answer gets one
point deducted, and no answer gets a zero.
Your task is to help the teacher automate this task.
Input
The first entry in the file contains answers to the test in the form:
TFFTFTFTFFFTTTTFTFTF

The next line is the number test cases, i.e. number of students who took the test.
Every other entry in the file is the student ID, followed by a blank, followed by the student's
responses. For example, the entry:

S2013-1-1003 TFTFTFTT TFTFTFFTTFT

indicates that the student ID is S2013-1-1003 and the answer to question 1 is True, the
answer to question 2 is False, and so on. This student did not answer question 9. The exam, in
this example, has 20 questions.
Output
The output should be the student's ID, followed by the answers, followed by the test score,
followed by the test grade. Assume the following grade scale: 90%-100%, A; 80%-89.99%, B;
70%-79.99%, C; 60%-69.99%, D; and 0%-59.99%, F.

Sample Input

TTTTTFFFFF

3

S2013-1-2345 TTTTTFFFFF

S2013-1-1266 TFTFTFTFTF

S2012-2-0006 T T TF F F

Sample Output

S2013-1-2345 TTTTTFFFFF 20 A

S2013-1-1266 TFTFTFTFTF 8 F

S2012-2-0006 T T TF F F 12 D

*/

**My code :**

```
public class Score {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //input answer to the test
        String correctAnswer = sc.nextLine(); 

        //input number of test cases
        int numberOfStudents = sc.nextInt();

        String studentID[] = new String[numberOfStudents];
        String studentAnswer[] = new String[numberOfStudents];
        int studentScore[] = new int[numberOfStudents];
        char studentGrade[] = new char[numberOfStudents];
        //ask user to input data
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter student details");
            studentID[i] = sc.nextLine();
            studentAnswer[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }//end of first for loop


        //checks whether the student has the correct score
        for(int y = 0; y < correctAnswer.length(); y++) {
            if(studentAnswer[y].charAt(y) == correctAnswer.charAt(y)) {
                studentScore[y]++;
            }//end of if
        }//end of for

        for(int y = 0; y < numberOfStudents; y ++) {
            double percentage = (studentScore[y] / correctAnswer.length()) * 100 ;

            //check the letter grade of the student
            if(percentage >= 90) {
                studentGrade[y] = 'A';
            }//end of first if
            else if(percentage >= 80 && percentage <= 89) {
                studentGrade[y] = 'B';
            }//end first else if
            else if(percentage >= 70 && percentage <= 79) {
                studentGrade[y] = 'C';
            }//end of second else if
            else if(percentage >= 60 && percentage <= 69) {
                studentGrade[y] = 'D';
            }//end of third else if
            else {
                studentGrade[y] = 'F';
            }//end of last else
        }//end of for
        //close the scanner to avoid any memory leaks

        //display the score
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d", studentID[i], studentAnswer[i], studentScore[i], studentGrade[i]);
        }//end of first for

    }//end of main
}//end of class
```

The program compiles and all however once I input my test data, i received an outofBounders error from my compiler. Then I realized that I had made a mistake in this code

```
            System.out.println("Enter student details");
            studentID[i] = sc.nextLine();
            studentAnswer[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }//end of first for loop
```

if StudentID and studentAnswer is an integer then I can seperate them by using space and enter my data in one line. However I forgot that when I use space as a seperator, it is not seperated as space is still considered a string. My main question here is how do I ask the user to input his student ID and his answer in one line seperated by a string so that I can store then into my arrays such as studentID array and studentAnswer array.

Comment: The sample input does not match the description: `The next line is the number test cases, i.e. number of students who took the test.` The 3 should not be on the same line as the correct answers. And it looks like entry stands for line, the first answer should also be on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

The format specifier that you use for display the score is wrong! you can can change it as below:

//display the score

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {

System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%d\t%s", studentID[i], studentAnswer[i], studentScore[i], studentGrade[i])

 }//end of first for
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking input using sc.nextLine(). What does nextLine() do is, it reads all character from input buffer until **\n** or **newline** character is found.

So you can ask user to give input something like this way:
**StudentID** \n **studentAnswer**

Another way you can modify your input taking array as like as this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter student details");
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    char[] chars = line.toCharArray();
    String fs = "";
    String sc = "";
    boolean flag = false;
    for(int j=0;j<chars.length;j++){
        if(chars[j]==' ') {
            flag = true;
            continue;
        }
        if(flag ==false) fs += chars[j];
        else sc += chars[j];
    }

    studentID[i] = fs;
    studentAnswer[i] = sc;
}
```